# How to avoid these segment lines when plot points in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I want to plot some points and a single line as follows:

```
  plot(x_t, y_t);
  hold on;
  plot(x,y,'o')
```

But the result is

[image]

These single points are connected by segment lines. How to avoid these segment lines?

Comment: Do you have to use `plot`? You could use `scatter` instead.

Comment: `plot(x,y,'o')` should only show markers, without a connecting line. It doesn't look like the code and image you've provided match, please include a [mcve]. Try using `clf` or creating a new `figure`, since you've used `hold on` it might be that you're seeing the remnants of an old plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use plot with a marker instead of a line:

```
 plot(x,y,'o');
```

Comment: @MatteoV It's not, but it's the correct syntax for a scatter plot without connecting lines using the `plot` function, it looks like the OP's code doesn't match their included image.